# ERROR: The term 'Import-PowerShellDataFile' is not recognized in Azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to use d365fo.tools in an Azure Functions, I added it to the dependencies

But when I try to import the module in my Azure function :

```
Import-Module d365fo.tools -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

I get the following error :

```
[2022-04-01T16:03:06.104Z] ERROR: The term 'Import-PowerShellDataFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Import-PowerShellDataFile` is usually available, but some PS versions like Nano don't load it. You could get around this by defining it yourself if it's missing, before loading the tools module. Like [sirAndros does here](https://github.com/devblackops/Terminal-Icons/issues/5#issuecomment-1057072605):

> ```
> if (!(Get-Command 'Import-PowerShellDataFile' -ErrorAction Ignore)) {
>     function Import-PowerShellDataFile {
>       [CmdletBinding()]
>       Param (
>           [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
>           [Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.ArgumentToConfigurationDataTransformation()]
>           [hashtable] $Path
>       )
>       return $Path
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Same error still :( I think it's related to Azure functions

Comment: @Maxime are you loading the example function **before** you import `d365fo.tools`? You may also want to try removing `-UseWindowsPowerShell` to troubleshoot. Since it has to load a new instance of powershell 5.1, it might not keep any functions you have defined up to that point

Comment: Yes i'm loading it before, the problem is when I do not use -UseWindowsPowerShell, I have the following error : ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
And the solution according to another stackoverflow question was to put the -UseWindowsPowerShell, which leads to this new error